# C++: Mask and decoding bits

Tags: c++, mask, masking

I just came across a function I dont understand, and I was wondering if you could explain it to me.

```
unsigned long long x(unsigned long long value, int begin, int end)
{
    unsigned long long mask = (1 << (end - begin)) - 1;
    return (value >> begin) & mask;
}
```

Thanks
uksz

Comment: Maybe you should take an example, e.g. `value = 1100111000110010`, `begin = 3`, `end = 7`, and work it out by hand...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above function serves as a mask to extract a range of bits from a number. It can be broken down into four steps.

First step:

```
mask = 1UL << (end - begin)
```

The `<<` logically shifts `1` to the left by `end - begin` bits. Since the binary of `1` is `000001`, a shift by 3 would correspond to `001000`.

Second step:

```
mask = mask - 1
```

We have established from the previous step that mask at that point would be a sequence of zeroes, followed a one, followed by `end - begin` number of zeroes. Subtracting `1` from such a number will result in the `end - begin` least significant bits being `1`, with everything else as `0`. Subtracting `1` from our previous example yields `000111`.

Third step:

```
value >> begin
```

This will logically shift the target number (the one from which we need to extract bits) to the right by `begin` bits. Since we want the bits in the range `begin to end`, we can leave remove the bits before `begin`.

Fourth step:

```
(value >> begin) & mask
```

Taking the characterwise AND with the mask will result in the first `begin - end` bits of the shifted number being extracted. This is because the `0 & x = 0` and `1 & x = x`.

As pointed out in the other answer by Bathsheba, care should be taken to write 1UL to ensure that the number being shifted is an `unsigned int`. Else shifting an `int` by more bits in that `int` is undefined behavior. 1UL is an `unsigned long long int` with the value `1`.

Comment: Or the compiler might just eat your cat. If you mention the UB, then this answer will be hard to better. (I don't mind at all you taking the main focus of my answer and putting it here).

Comment: @Bathsheba : Mentioning the UB, with proper credit of course.

Comment: It needs to be 1ULL by the way.

Comment: That's the nature of undefined behaviour. You **must** use 1ULL to guarantee it working.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of the function is **undefined**. It should be

`unsigned long long mask = (1ULL << (end - begin)) - 1;`

`1` is an `int` literal and applying more left shifts than there are bits in that `int` is undefined behaviour. `1ULL` is an unsigned long long literal.

Once this is fixed, it will reliably return just the 0 and 1 bits in the range begin to end, and 0 everywhere else.

Comment: Hmm. Do you know from the top of your head, if `0ULL - 1` is defined? If `end == sizeof(unsigned long long)` and `begin == 0`, we end up with that.

Comment: 0ULL - 1 is equal to std::numeric_limits(unsigned long long)::max(). The standard insists on that wraparound for unsigned types.

Answer (score 1):

The first line is shifting to the left the number by a number of (end - begin) bit shifts.
The second line is shifting to the right by a number of (right) bit shifts.
This way at the end you will have a mask that is equal to the bits between "begin" and "end".

Answer (score 1):

```
(1) 1 in the expression implies 32 bit number on 32 bit machines.  
So we need uul after 1 to make it 64 bit. Will work for MOST of the              
cases.          
unsigned long long mask = (1ull << (end - begin)) - 1;  

(2) When begin=0, end=63, we will still see the wrong mask in case#1  
The mask will come out be 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  
The following will fix that problem as well.  
unsigned long long mask = ((1ull << end) - (1ull << begin)) | (1ull << end);

This will generate the mask 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```