# Cheking a pattern of bits in a sequence

Tags: c++, c

So basically i need to check if a certain sequence of bits occurs in other sequence of bits(32bits). 
The function shoud take 3 arguments:

1. n right most bits of a value.
2. a value
3. the sequence where the n bits should be checked for occurance

The function has to return the number of bit where the desired sequence started. Example chek if last 3 bits of 0x5 occur in 0xe1f4.

```
void bitcheck(unsigned int source, int operand,int n)
{
   int i,lastbits,mask;
   mask=(1<<n)-1;
   lastbits=operand&mask;

   for(i=0; i<32; i++)
   {
      if((source&(lastbits<<i))==(lastbits<<i))
          printf("It start at bit number %i\n",i+n);
   }
}
```

Comment: Only yesterday I saw this question that extracts a number of consecutive bits from a number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781952/c-mask-and-decoding-bits#comment55330492_33781952

Comment: That isn't exactly what i need so i found the way of getting last n bits of the value then i need to check this pattern of n bits occurs in other sequence, for example check if 101 occurs in 111000111110100. And the function has to return the bit number where the pattern has started

Comment: @PandaHru please indent your code.

Comment: The code worked for a while when checking short patterns now it doesn't work at all

Comment: The part `(lastbits<<1)` is not clear, maybe not correct. Shoulden't be `(lastbits<<i)`?

Comment: ...and shouldn't be `printf("It start at bit number %i\n",i); `?

Comment: oh yes it should be     (lastbits<<i) but deffinetly printf("It starts at bit number &i\n, i+n);, if it would chek for 1 bit pattern it would be ,i ok but if the pattern is bigger it should be i+n

Comment: So when executing for example checking last 2 bits of value 5  for occurence in the sequence of bits in 9 the result is 2 and 5 for real 01 occurs in 01001 at bits number 2 and 5 but if i take the occurence of last 3  bits of 5 (=101) in 0xe1f4(1110000111110100) the sequence only appears at bit number 5 but the function  has other results as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop goes too far, I'm afraid. It could, for example 'find' the bit pattern '0001' in a value `~0`, which consists of ones only.

This will do better (I hope):

```
void checkbit(unsigned value, unsigned pattern, unsigned n)
{
    unsigned size = 8 * sizeof value;
    if( 0 < n && n <= size)
    {
        unsigned mask = ~0U >> (size - n);
        pattern &= mask;

        for(int i = 0; i <= size - n; i ++, value >>= 1)
            if((value & mask) == pattern)
                printf("pattern found at bit position %u\n", i+n);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much better,best regards

Answer (score 0):

I take you to mean that you want to take `source` as a bit array, and to search it for a bit sequence specified by the `n` lowest-order bits of `operand`.  It seems you would want to perform a standard mask & compare; the only (minor) complication being that you need to scan.  You seem already to have that idea.

I'd write it like this:

```
void bitcheck(uint32_t source, uint32_t operand, unsigned int n) {
    uint32_t mask = ~((~0) << n);
    uint32_t needle = operand & mask;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= (32 - n); i += 1) {
        if (((source >> i) & mask) == needle) {
            /* found it */
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

There are some differences in the details between mine and yours, but the main functional difference is the loop bound: you must be careful to ignore cases where some of the bits you compare against the target were introduced by a shift operation, as opposed to originating in `source`, lest you get false positives.  The way I've written the comparison makes it clearer (to me) what the bound should be.

I also use the explicit-width integer data types from `stdint.h` for all values where the code depends on a specific width.  This is an excellent habit to acquire if you want to write code that ports cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
if((source&(maskbits<<i))==(lastbits<<i))
```

Because:
finding 10 in 11 will be true for your old code. In fact, your original condition will always return true when 'source' is made of all ones.